# Не понимаю, почему возникает missing ) after argument list

Tags: jquery

Строка:

```
$('#contact-bottom').css('background' : '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%');
```

Ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Весь отрезок кода, находящийся в аяксе:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST", //Метод отправки
                    url: "mail.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function() {
                       console.log("Message successfuly send");
                       $("#mail-button").detach();
                       $('#contact-bottom').css('background' : '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропущены скобки `{ }` необходимые для создания объекта - аргумента функции `$().css`:

```
$('#contact-bottom').css(
  { 'background' : '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%' }
);
```

или замените  `:` на `,`:

```
$('#contact-bottom').css(
  'background', '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Конструкции `('string': 'string')` в `JS` вызывают вопросы - к чему двоеточие?
Выхода 2:

1. Превратить это в объект, где `:` легален:
   `({'background' : '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'});`.
2. Либо отказаться от этой конструкции (в `jQuery` можно задать одно правило
   так: `('background', '#3F51B5 url(' + 'img/check.png' + ') no-repeat 50% 50%');`).